# Difference between fullPage and captureBeyondViewport

Tags: puppeteer

The puppeteer function [`page.screenshot([options])`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagescreenshotoptions) accepts two parameters:

- `fullPage`  When true, takes a screenshot of the full scrollable page. Defaults to `false`.
- `captureBeyondViewport`  When true, captures screenshot [beyond the viewport](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-captureScreenshot). Whe false, falls back to old behaviour, and cuts the screenshot by the viewport size. Defaults to `true`.

To me this sounds like pretty much the same thing, besides the different default values. So I wonder what the difference is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These options might seem like siblings, but they are not and have very different behavior from each other and doesn't relate to each other at all.

### fullPage

The `fullPage` option technically [resizes the viewport to match the page layout width and height when taking a screenshot and then returns a viewport size to the previous value](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/6bc152ece01371da519bc942967540751fd93b2a/packages/puppeteer-core/src/common/Page.ts#L1379). So, that's how you get the whole page screenshot.

### captureBeyondViewport

Not related to the issue, you might have cases when an element or even the whole page width or height is defined through viewport units. Look at this example ([source](https://screenshotone.com/blog/capture-beyond-viewport-in-puppeteer-and-chrome-devtools-protocol/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div 
            class="beyond-viewport-element" 
            style="height: 110vh; background-color: blue; border: 10px solid red"></div>
        <div 
            class="next-element" 
            style="height: 100px; background-color: yellow; border: 10px solid black"></div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

If you try to take the full-page screenshot, you will fail to take it fully because the `.beyond-viewport-element` will always be beyond the viewport, so to make sure that you capture elements beyond the viewport, set the `captureBeyondViewport` option to `true`.